# 3D Reconstruct from multiple view

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction, homogenous-transformation

I have a computer vision problem recostruction:

I have **multiple view** took with an **uncalibrated camera** (from wich i know to have **fx = fy = f, s=0**, and the parameters not varying)

The points that I can match from the different views all lay on a common plane.
I can also match from the scene 4 different lines (lets say **L1,L2,L3,L4**)

such that: **L1 is parallel with L2, L3 is parallel with L4 and L1 is orthogonal with L3 (and L4)**...

I have enough views (9), and enough points (6 without the corner of the 4 lines).

I would like to use all *the information i wrote to reduce noise*, and I am asked to compute everything with the normalized images (that i don't know what does it means) to reduce numerical errors.

It is given also the distance between two of the matching points.

It is required to: *reconstruct the scene* (all the 6 3D points), r*econstruct the camera internal parameter* (ux, vx and f), and *reconstruct the camera positions* of the images.

So.

I studied the **8Point algorithm**, but that algoritm (if i understood well) it is working with only two view, and more, **it is not working with points laying on a plane**.

I studied the **4Point algorithm**, that is made for points laying on a same plane, but it requires only two views (*and i would like to use all the views)* and doesn't involves lines. Then other problem is that I don't understand how to reconstruct R and T (that are fundamental, if i understood well to reconstruct the position of the camera) from P.

Than i studied an iterative model that u can find at this paper:

[3D Reconstruction with Uncalibrated Camera](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Takeo_Kanade/publication/2454329_Creating_3D_Models_with_Uncalibrated_Cameras/links/00b7d5214f19579c6f000000.pdf)

but I'm not able (and i even don't know what is it) to perform rank 4 decomposition in matlab.

I don't ask you of course to give me a detailed solution of my problem, obvisiully, but of course I would like to understand at least wich way i should take to solve my problem in a correct way, then i can google more, and i can study more.

I thank you all for your time

Comment: FYI, sfmedu is implemented recursively from two views. http://vision.princeton.edu/courses/SFMedu/ Its code may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have enough data to calibrate the camera. Read, e.g, Z. Zhang's [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/TR98-71.pdf).